# TFS 2008 Build and deploy to Inetpub web folder

Tags: build, automation, deployment

I have TFS2008 and have a build running, however, I want to automate the deployment of the build folder and place the build into the inetpub folder it belongs to.

I.E.:

1. Run Build
2. After Build, automatically place the new built solution into Inetpub/wwwroot/websitefolder

I have tried xcopy, robocopy and synctoy 2.1 and I cannot get any of them to work.

(xcopy use)

```
<Exec Command="xcopy $(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Debug\_PublishedWebsites\IPAMIntranet C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\IPAMOnlineSystem.Test /E " />
```

(robocopy use)

```
<Exec Command="ROBOCOPY $(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Debug\_PublishedWebsites\IPAMIntranet C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\IPAMOnlineSystem.Test /S /XJ /B /R:5" />
```

(synctoy 2.1 use)

```
<Exec Command="SyncToyCmd.exe -RIPAMBuildProjectDeploy" />
```

Can anyone at all please help me with this dilemna?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been effectively resolved by using MSDeploy.